# PowerShell script cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled

Tags: powershell, executionpolicy

I was running a script just fine on my PC. It crashed and I got a new one and I keep getting this error.
(File C:\Users\19257\Desktop\DriveMaps.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this
system.) So, I know the script if good. It runs on other people's computers.

WHAT I HAVE TRIED.

1. Verified my PC is in the correct AD OU. Same as everyone else that can run the script.
2. I ran PowerShell as admin and tried these commands and get the same error.

- `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`
- `Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`
- `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope LocalMachine`

3. My setting are currently like this:

```
Scope ExecutionPolicy
----- ---------------
MachinePolicy       Undefined
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process       Undefined
  CurrentUser       Undefined
 LocalMachine       Undefined
```

Answer (score -2):

I figured it out. Instead of running Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned in PowerShell as admin. I ran it in PowerShell ISE as admin and it worked!

Comment: It's commendable that you're trying to show others what worked (I didn't down-vote), but note that execution policies aren't tied to a particular host. In order to set the `LocalMachine` policy, the only thing that matters is whether your session - whether in the IDE or in a regular console window -  is elevated or not. Therefore, I don't think your solution will help future readers.